# template typedef c++0x

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, typedef

I have found several questions asking about template typedefs in C++0x, which are resolved with the `using` keyword; however, with GCC 4.6.1 (running `g++ -std=c++0x`), I get the following error:

*error: expected unqualified-id before ‘using’*

Can you help me find where I'm going wrong? I've been trying to solve this for hours...

**Code:**

```
#include <map>

template<typename INDEX, typename VALUE>
class GenericSparseVector
{
protected:
  std::map<INDEX, VALUE> indices_to_values;
};

template <typename VALUE>
using StandardSparseVector = GenericSparseVector<int, VALUE>;
```

Comment: Just a guess, try `template <typename VALUE> using StandardSparseVector<VALUE> = GenericSparseVector<int, VALUE>;`

Comment: Hmm... still no luck. It looks like I don't have a new enough version of GCC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Template aliases are supported starting in gcc 4.7.

Comment: Oh, I can't believe I tried for so long! I was sure I was missing a semicolon like everyone else asking... Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I had prototyped some code using clang (Apple clang version 4.1) but when I switched to Linux using gcc 4.6.1 it no longer compiled.